# Single Sign On with Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a bunch of web apps that I've created. Some of them use old-style webforms authentication, and some other sites at our company use different authentication patterns.

I'm trying to consolidate this, under one SSO pattern using Azure Active Directory. I've been trying to following guides/tutorials but it's not clicking for me.

My tech is currently ASP 4/MVC 5, although if ASP 5/MVC 6 is easier then I have the freedom to go that route as well. All web apps are hosted in Azure currently.

The confusion for me comes in that while looking through documentation, there seem to be so many ways to authentication and authorize users (also, authenticate vs authorize isn't absolutely clear to me).

I went to the Active Directory area of Azure Management portal (the old one). I added a new application called `TestApp`. I set the app URL to `https://localhost:44320/`, then sign-on URL to `https://localhost:44320/`, the tenant name to `testapp`. And my reply URL is `https://localhost:44320/`

This makes my app id uri `https://localhost:44320/testapp` I think? I also have my client ID guid.

The tutorial has an `AccountController` with a `SignIn` method like this:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

When navigating to this, I receive the following in the browser:

> [InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44320/testapp/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]

I have a feeling it's because Azure is unable to redirect this all to back to my localhost? How can I set this up so I can test it out on Azure itself? And even further than that, will this solution be usable from multiple webapps? I'd assume they'd each be different applications in my Active Directory, but they'd all need to use a SSO procedure, where users can sign into multiple apps with one identity.

Sorry for any confusion, this is all very convoluted to me but I am trying to learn it as best I can.

Edit:

In the Startup of the webapp, I am calling this:

```
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Which utilizes these app.config settings:

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="[my client id here]" />
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="testapp" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://localhost:44320/{0}" />
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44320/" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure is able to redirect to localhost, it will just pop up a security confirmation asking if its ok to navigate to localhost.

Your tenant in app.config doesn't look right, change these app settings:

```
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="[YOUR TENANT].onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
```

To find out more about your tenant see this article: [How to get an Azure Active Directory tenant](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-howto-tenant/)

You can also try adding this code to your Notifications in Startup (just under AuthenticationFailed), try putting breakpoints on the handlers to see what happens:

```
AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },     
SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
```

Put an [Authorize] attribute on one of your controllers and it should redirect to the AAD authentication when you browse to it.

AFAIK each app would need a separate application in Azure AD and you would need to implement this Authentication in each separate app. I have managed to have a seamless sign in experience when I link via url from one app to another.

This answer sums up authentication vs authorization nicely: [Authentication versus Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556548/2401021)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One question. You said you managed to have a seamless sign in experience when you link via url from one app to another. Do you mean you're able to have more than one app utilize the same sign on credentials simultaneously? Or does a user need to sign up for each app individually?

Comment: @mariocatch not exactly sure how/why it works cause I'm still busy experimenting myself but basically I have two apps which both implement authentication as above using AAD. If I browse to each app individually they will prompt for credentials. However if I log into app 1 and access app 2 via a link then app 2 doesn't prompt for authentication. I can see by the requests that app 2 still first goes to Azure but seems to authenticate automatically and returns without going to the login page.