# Restricting Access to method in Play Framework with Authorization - Java

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.5, deadbolt-2

I am having trouble grasping the idea of authorization in PlayFramework (version 2.5). My situation is I have a REST API method `getUser` and I want to restrict its access by performing authorization with a token that is coming in custom request header named `"X-Authorization"`. Now my controller code looks like that:

```
package controllers;

import models.User;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import play.mvc.*;
import org.json.simple.*;
import views.html.*;

public class ApiController extends Controller {

    public Result getUser(String userId) {

        User user = User.findById(new ObjectId(userId));
        JSONObject userG = new JSONObject();

        //Some code to append data to userG before return
        return ok(userG.toJSONString());
    }
}
```

The route URL is defined like this:

```
GET    /api/user/:id    controllers.ApiController.getUser(id)
```

**Option 1** could be to check the Authorization token inside the method `getUser` and also check for other credentials but I want to restrict access before even it get calls `getUser` method. As in future I will be adding more method calls to this REST API. So I will be reusing the same authorization to those future REST APIs as well.

I found there is [authorization](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide4) available in Play Framework which I am not able to understand. I tried to implement Authorization by extending class `Security.Authenticator` and overriding methods `getUserName` and `onUnauthorized` like this:

```
package controllers;

import models.Site;
import models.User;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import play.mvc.Http.Context;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Security;

public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {
    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        String auth_key = ctx.request().getHeader("X-Authorization");
        Site site = Site.fineByAccessKey(auth_key);

        if (site != null && auth_key.equals(site.access_key)) {
            return auth_key;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {

        JSONObject errorAuth = new JSONObject();
        errorAuth.put("status", "error");
        errorAuth.put("msg", "You are not authorized to access the API");

        return unauthorized(errorAuth.toJSONString());
    }
}
```

Then I've appended the annotation to the `getUser` method with `@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)`. It works fine and returns unauthorized error. But now I am not sure if that is the preferred way. I feel this is not the right way to do it as the name of the override of function `getUsername` suggests that too. I am not checking for any username in session or cookie rather only the token present in the header of request.

Also I know there is a module named [`Deadbolt`](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java) which is used for authorization but I read its documents and I am not able to integrate it. It was relatively complex integration for a beginner like me. I was confused about how to use it. I thought about using [`SubjectPresent`](https://deadbolt-java.readme.io/v2.5/docs/controller-constraints#section-subjectpresent-and-subjectnotpresent) controller authorization but still I was not able to implement it successfully.

In the end what do you guys suggest that should I use `Security.Authenticator` the way I have implemented? Or do you suggest that I go to my first option that is checking authorization inside `getUser` method? Or Anyone can tell me how to implement [`Deadbolt`](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java) in my scenario?

Comment: Just for anyone who wants to know how to implement `Security.Authenticated`. i found this following nice article which might be a good help: https://alexgaribay.com/2014/06/16/authentication-in-play-framework-using-java/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing Authorization and Authentication.

Here is a good thread:  [Authentication versus Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556522/authentication-versus-authorization)

I like this answer:

> **Authentication** = login + password (who you are)
>
> **Authorization** = permissions (what you are allowed to do)

**Authentication** == **Authorization** (excluding anonymous user) if you allow doing something for all users that you know (i.e. **Authenticated** users)

The main goal of [Deadbolt](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java) is **Authorization** (already Authenticated users). Your main goal is **Authentication**.

I would advise you to use [Pac4J](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j), it **Authentication** library not only for Play, and it has versions as for Java as for Scala. There is a good sample project: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo

I use this library myself in my projects and the task

> As in future i will be adding more method calls to this REST api. So i
>   will be reusing the same authorization to those future REST apis as
>   well.

I solve as easy as just add the configuration in the 'application.conf`:

```
pac4j.security {
  rules = [
    {"/admin/.*" = {
      authorizers = "ADMIN"
      clients = "FormClient"
    }}
  ]
}
```

Just do not forget to add Security filter. This feature present in the example project, so just clone and try.

Another example form [the official page](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j):

```
pac4j.security.rules = [
  # Admin pages need a special authorizer and do not support login via Twitter.
  {"/admin/.*" = {
    authorizers = "admin"
    clients = "FormClient"
  }}
  # Rules for the REST services. These don't specify a client and will return 401
  # when not authenticated.
  {"/restservices/.*" = {
    authorizers = "_authenticated_"
  }}
  # The login page needs to be publicly accessible.
  {"/login.html" = {
    authorizers = "_anonymous_"
  }}
  # 'Catch all' rule to make sure the whole application stays secure.
  {".*" = {
    authorizers = "_authenticated_"
    clients = "FormClient,TwitterClient"
  }}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about authentication and authorization. i will look into pac4j module.