# How do I use AWS cognito response to authenticate API requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am building a web app that authenticates via AWS Cognito, and uses an existing API gateway configuration to talk to Lambda functions.

In my app, when I authenticate, I get the following data back from Cognito:

[image]

The sample headers I've been given to authenticate to the Amazon API gateway look like this (x's added for obfuscation):

```
Content-type: application/json
Host: <API Gateway host>
X-Amz-DateL <Date>
Authorization:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXX/20170222/ap-southeast-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=f25e2a18d8c81fe9e7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXb7d586d24a3e39
Access_key:XXXXXXXX (this is a large string)
```

My question is what information do I need from my cognito result to craft the headers that I need to connect to the api?

I'm using Vue.js as a Javascript front end, and I've looked at the AWS SDK for Javascript but not sure if that helps me - for the moment I feel crafting the headers manually may be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is *authorize* your already authenticated users. Explanation of the difference between authorization and authentication can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556522/authentication-versus-authorization)

In the case of **authorization**, you can create a [Custom Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html). However, since you're using Amazon Cognito, be sure to create a [Cognito User Pool Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)

Essentially, you'll use the `IdToken` from Cognito and pass it as the `Authorization` header to your authorizer function.

See also [Integrating Amazon Cognito User Pools with API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/)