# .NET Core 2.0 Authorization filter causes an internal error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

An authorization filter will cause an internal error on a .NET Core 2.0 web application. Steps to reproduce the problem are very simple: create a new .NET Core 2.0 MVC project with "no authentication", put an authorization filter on a controller method, access the corresponding URL and a "500 Internal Server Error" will be returned.

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

A similar code in .NET Core 1.1 will correctly return the response "401 Unauthorized".

I had a posted a similar question on the problem: [Custom cookie authentication not working after migration from ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073548/custom-cookie-authentication-not-working-after-migration-from-asp-net-core-1-1-m) while I still hadn't understood that the problem is much wider than it was in my specific case.

The exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.<ChallengeAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Run it under the debugger our check the logs to see the error.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to add any of the corresponding Authentication components in Startup.

Comment: Show us at least the exception, without it we have not the slightest idea what could be wrong

Comment: Authentication determines who the user is, otherwise he's anonymous, and authorization has to deal with it. Anyway, even if I do authenticate the user, the same error will occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 401 Unauthorized response [should contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) `WWW-Authenticate` header that defines authentication method for accessing the resource.

In your project created without authentication, there is no any default authentication scheme set. That's why authentication middleware can not build valid 401 response and chooses to send 500 error instead.

The fix is pretty simple. Add any authentication handler and set default authentication scheme, e.g.:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer();
}
```

With such configuration unauthorized request will result to 401 response with correctly set `WWW-Authenticate` header:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073548/custom-cookie-authentication-not-working-after-migration-from-asp-net-core-1-1-m) where a custom authetication actually exists.