# How to correctly setup Policy Authorization for WEB API in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this Web API project, with no UI. My `appsettings.json` file has a section listing tokens and which client they belong to. So the client will need to just present a matching token in the header. If no token is presented or an invalid one,  then it should be returning a 401.

In ConfigureServices I setup authorization

```
.AddTransient<IAuthorizationRequirement, ClientTokenRequirement>()
.AddAuthorization(opts => opts.AddPolicy(SecurityTokenPolicy, policy =>
 {
       var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
       policy.Requirements.Add(sp.GetService<IAuthorizationRequirement>());
 }))
```

This part fires correctly from what I can see.
Here is code for the ClientTokenRequirement

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ClientTokenRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext authFilterContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_tokenName))
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Token not provided");

            var httpContext = authFilterContext.HttpContext;

            if (!httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(_tokenName, out var tokenValues))
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            var tokenValueFromHeader = tokenValues.FirstOrDefault();

            var matchedToken = _tokens.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Token == tokenValueFromHeader);

            if (matchedToken != null)
            {       
                httpContext.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

When we are in the `ClientTokenRequirement` and have not matched a token it returns

```
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

This is done how it is documented at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

This works correctly when there is a valid token, but when there isnt and it returns `Task.Completed`, there is no 401 but an exception instead

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

I have read other stackoverflow articles about using Authentication rather than Authorization, but really this policy Authorization is the better fit for purpose. So I am looking for ideas on how to prevent this exception.

Comment: I see a lot of answers on StackOverflow that make use of "return Task.CompletedTask;" in method HandleRequirementAsync. But C# is not happy with that. It only accepts "return;" with compiler error CS1997 : "Since is an async method that returns Task, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interestingly, I think this is just *authentication*, without any *authorisation* (at least not in your question). You certainly want to *authenticate* the client but you don't appear to have any *authorisation* requirements. Authentication is the process of determining *who* is making this request and authorisation is the process of determining what said requester *can do* once we know who it is (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556522/authentication-versus-authorization)). You've indicated that you want to return a `401` (bad credentials) rather than a `403` (unauthorised), which I believe highlights the difference (more [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2014/10/02/401-vs-403/)).

In order to use your own authentication logic in ASP.NET Core, you can write your own `AuthenticationHandler`, which is responsible for taking a request and determining the [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Here's an example for your situation:

```
public class ClientTokenHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ClientTokenOptions>
{
    private readonly string[] _clientTokens;

    public ClientTokenHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ClientTokenOptions> optionsMonitor,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UrlEncoder urlEncoder, ISystemClock systemClock,
        IConfiguration config)
        : base(optionsMonitor, loggerFactory, urlEncoder, systemClock)
    {
        _clientTokens = config.GetSection("ClientTokens").Get<string[]>();
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var tokenHeaderValue = (string)Request.Headers["X-TOKEN"];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenHeaderValue))
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());

        if (!_clientTokens.Contains(tokenHeaderValue))
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unknown Client"));

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
            Enumerable.Empty<Claim>(),
            Scheme.Name));
        var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, Scheme.Name);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket));
    }
}
```

Here's a description of what's going on in `HandleAuthenticateAsync`:

1. The header `X-TOKEN` is retrieved from the request. If this is invalid, we indicate that we are unable to authenticate the request (more on this later).
2. The value retrieved from the `X-TOKEN` header is compared against a known list of client-tokens. If this is unsuccessful, we indicate that authentication failed (we don't know who this is - more on this later too).
3. When a client-token matches the `X-TOKEN` request header, we create a new `AuthenticationTicket`/`ClaimsPrincipal`/`ClaimsIdentity` combo. This is our representation of the `User` - you can include your own `Claim`s instead of using `Enumerable.Empty<Claim>()` if you want to associate additional information with the client.

You should be able to use this as-is for the most part, with a few changes (I've simplified to both keep the answer short and fill in a few gaps from the question):

1. The constructor takes an instance of `IConfiguration` as the final parameter, which is then used to read a `string[]` from, in my example, `appsettings.json`. You are likely doing this differently, so you can just use DI to inject whatever it is you're currently using here, as needed.
2. I've hardcoded `X-TOKEN` as the header name to use when extracting the token. You'll likely be using a different name for this yourself and I can see from your question that you're not hardcoding it, which is better.

One other thing to note about this implementation is the use of both `AuthenticateResult.NoResult()` and `AuthenticateResult.Fail(...)`. The former indicates that we did not have enough information in order to perform the authentication and the latter indicates that we had everything we needed but the authentication failed. For a simple setup like yours, I think you'd be OK using `Fail` in both cases if you'd prefer.

The second thing you'll need is the `ClientTokenOptions` class, which is used above in `AuthenticationHandler<ClientTokenOptions>`. For this example, this is a one-liner:

```
public class ClientTokenOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions { }
```

This is used for configuring your `AuthenticationHandler` - feel free to move some of the configuration into here (e.g. the _clientTokens from above). It also depends on how configurable and reusable you want this to be - as another example, you could define the header name in here, but that's up to you.

Lastly, to use your `ClientTokenHandler`, you'll need to add the following to `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication("ClientToken")
    .AddScheme<ClientTokenOptions, ClientTokenHandler>("ClientToken", _ => { });
```

Here, we're just registering `ClientTokenHandler` as an `AuthenticationHandler` under our own custom `ClientToken` scheme. I wouldn't hardcode `"ClientToken"` here like this, but, again, this is just a simplification. The funky `_ => { }` at the end is a callback that is given an instance of `ClientTokenOptions` to modify: we don't need that here, so it's just an empty lambda, effectively.

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

The "DefaultChallengeScheme" in your error message has now been set with the call to `services.AddAuthentication("ClientToken")` above ("ClientToken" is the scheme name).

---

If you want to go with this approach, you'll need to remove your `ClientTokenRequirement` stuff. You might also find it interesting to have a look through Barry Dorrans's [BasicAuthentication](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication) project - it follows the same patterns as the official ASP.NET Core `AuthenticationHandler`s but is simpler for getting started. If you're not concerned about the configurability and reusability aspects, the implementation I've provided should be fit for purpose.