# Authentication and authorization with Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-web-app-service

Please share the difference between authentication and authorization with Microsoft identity management and authorization with app service in azure active directory. I have to build a ASP.NET web application which will be hosted with in the organisation and accessible only to people with in the organisation.Please let me know which one to choose(App service or microsoft identity management correctly and different scenarios where these are used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556548/1384539

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure AD scope:

Authentication is the process of proving you are who you say you are. Authentication is sometimes shortened to AuthN. Microsoft identity platform implements the OpenID Connect protocol for handling authentication.

Authorization is the act of granting an authenticated party permission to do something. It specifies what data you're allowed to access and what you can do with that data. Authorization is sometimes shortened to AuthZ. Microsoft identity platform implements the OAuth 2.0 protocol for handling authorization.

Here you have full quickstart documentation, how to create a web app with a sign-in option within Microsoft Identity Platform: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp

Sample application scenarios: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-scenarios